auto type dedection of `auto x = {1,2,3};`
Traditionally, people read a variable declaration/definition from left to right, for example:
std::vector<float> arr = {3.14, 1.414, 2.71, -0.2};

So the meaning of {3.14, 1.414, 2.71, -0.2} is clear: we have an std::vector<float> type variable arr, we want to initialize it with four elements: 3.14, 1.414, 2.71, -0.2
But the introduction of auto makes this a bit more obscure. What does the following auto keyword do?:
auto arr = {3.14, 1.414, 2.71, -0.2};

My clangd hints that here arr is: std::initializer_list<double>, is this the unique type deduction result across all standard-complaint compilers or some compilers are free to make auto arr an std::vector<double> here?
A more detailed and sophisticated example:, I have a template function to get the max value from exactly three std::vectors:
template <typename T>
constexpr T getMax(const std::vector<T> &v1, const std::vector<T> &v2, const std::vector<T> &v3)
{
    auto arr = { std::views::all(v1), std::views::all(v2), std::views::all(v3)};
    auto view = std::views::join(arr);
    return std::ranges::max(view);
}

In this snippet we defined an auto arr variable:
auto arr = { std::views::all(v1), std::views::all(v2), std::views::all(v3)};

its deduced type from gcc is: std::initializer_list<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<std::string_view>>>, what mandates the compiler that the auto type must have been deduced to this lengthy concrete type? Is this result unique or each compiler is free to make their own deduction as long as they follow some rules?

"this lengthy concrete type": It is always just the (shared) type of the elements given as template argument to std::initializer_list. std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<std::string_view>> is the type of std::views::all(v1).

The compiler is deducing auto to std::initializer_list

@user17732522 regarding std::initializer_list<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<std::string_view>>>, how about the T part, i.e., std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<std::string_view>>

Why does auto x{3} deduce an initializer_list? and Scott mayer's presentation

@D.J.Elkind That's just the type that std::views::all is specified to return if the argument is of type std::vector<std::string_view>.

It should always be an std::initializer_list. It won't be std::vector, the same braced-init-list can also be used to initialize a raw array, or std::list etc.
[dcl.type.auto.deduct]/3
(emphasis mine)

If the placeholder-type-specifier is of the form
type-constraintopt auto, the deduced type T′ replacing T is
determined using the rules for template argument deduction. If the
initialization is copy-list-initialization, a declaration of
std​::​initializer_list shall precede ([basic.lookup.general]) the
placeholder-type-specifier. Obtain P from T by replacing the
occurrences of type-constraintopt auto either with a new
invented type template parameter U or, if the initialization is
copy-list-initialization, with std​::​initializer_list<U>. Deduce a
value for U using the rules of template argument deduction from a
function call, where P is a function template parameter type and the
corresponding argument is E. If the deduction fails, the declaration
is ill-formed. Otherwise, T′ is obtained by substituting the deduced U
into P.
[Example 1:
auto x1 = { 1, 2 };             // decltype(x1) is std​::​initializer_list<int>
auto x2 = { 1, 2.0 };           // error: cannot deduce element type
auto x3{ 1, 2 };                // error: not a single element
auto x4 = { 3 };                // decltype(x4) is std​::​initializer_list<int>
auto x5{ 3 };                   // decltype(x5) is int

— end example]

